# Do While loop not looping nor doing

Tags: vba, excel, do-while

In a quest to further never do anythign manual ever again
I made an it.xlsm that you have to put together in a folder with a specific file that has to be processed.

This it.xslm has three modules:

**Masterfile**
- renames the categories in C
-makes a worksheet per category in C
-saves those worksheets as .xslx. This results in 8 new files in a /Departement folder

**Littlefiles**
-renames the categories in E
-makes tabs for each category
-cleans up empty columns.

**placeholder**
Opens the .xls with the data
Applies Masterfile
Opens all the files created by masterfiles
makes tabs and cleans up empty columns.

Placeholder's code:

```
Sub OpenBigFile()
Dim wb As Workbook

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Lastrow As Long
'open main file, apply masterfile moduke
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.path & "\Depositformulier (Reacties).xlsx")

Call masterfile.total

wb.Close SaveChanges:=True

End Sub
```

This works fine.

```
    Sub OpenAllFiles()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String


   myPath = ThisWorkbook.path & "\" & "Departement" & "\"
   myFile = Dir(myPath & "*.xlsx")


  Do While Len(Filename) > 0
  DoEvents
     Set wb = Workbooks.Open(myPath & myFile, True, True)

        Call LittleFiles.total

      wb.Close False

      myFile = Dir
  Loop


End Sub
```

Here I find myself in problems. I tried to rewrite it many times, using many examples, but always it seems to be stuck at `Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)`

**What am I doing wrong?**
Do you need my Littlefiles code?

Also, in general, is it correct that 'ThisWorkbook' will always refer to the this.xlm,even if in the mean time another workbook is active (this being ActiveWorkbook)?

Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my attempt, i think this way it'll be harder to go wrong as you will have the full path of the file already stored:

```
Sub OpenAllFiles()
'create an array
Dim myFiles As Variant
ReDim myFiles(500)

myPath = ThisWorkbook.Path

If Right(myPath, 1) <> "\" Then
myPath = myPath & "\"
End If


'search for at least 5 files in the folder specified above, add the entire path to the array
While myCount < 5
    If Dir(myPath & "*.xlsm") <> "" Then
    potentialFileToLoad = Dir(myPath & "*.xlsm")
    While potentialFileToLoad <> ""
        myFiles(myCount) = myPath & potentialFileToLoad
        myCount = myCount + 1
        potentialFileToLoad = Dir
    Wend

    End If
Wend

'change size of array to ammount of files found
ReDim Preserve myFiles(myCount - 1)

For Each ii In myFiles

'(Insert Open, Run code, close code here)
Workbooks.Open (ii), True, True

Call LittleFiles.Total

ActiveWorkbook.Close

Next ii

End Sub
```

Comment: By full path allready stored you mean '"C:\Users\BillyBob\Documents\Reports\Department\" ? Because The file is not supposed to have a fixed location. You think the problem is the Thisworkbook.path?

Edit: A msgbox myPath seems to give me the right path...

Comment: could be the issue, because if the workbook isnt in a filepath that ends in "Department" then it wont work. 

for example if the file is in C:\Users\BillyBob\Documents\Reports

and you add "\Department\" to the path. then it wont find the files.

Comment: Just edited my original answer with thisworkbook.path. Can you see if it works?

Comment: yes ofcourse. So vba only works in a fixed path? I find that hard to believe. Also I really hope not or all these hours of trying to make this cool amcro would be wasted. :D 
i just did If myPath = "\\alpaca.int\User\Personeel\ANW\AP\Home\p092504\Desktop\a\Departementen\" Then MsgBox "ok" Else MsgBox "error" and I get an okay, which shows that at least here the ThisWorkbook.path and Doug's extra aid work. I will now try your solution.

Comment: my edited solution tries to find the path where ever the file is (dynamic path) - does that work?

Comment: changed to myPath = ThisWorkbook.path & "\" & "Departementen" & "\"  
AND If Dir(myPath & "*.xlsm") to .xlsx

I get an error 9 sub out of range on Workbooks(ii).Close (False)
Your code is a little to advanced for me (or at least unknow) to fix by myself :)

Comment: try changing `Workbooks(ii).Close (False)` to `activeworkbook.close(false)`

Comment: EDIT NO SORRY MY BAD

Comment: Just done another quick edit - when searching for the files (previous attempt kept adding same file to list).

Also, before running code, right click on "myFiles" and click "Add Watch..." > "OK. You can then see the files being added to the array.

Comment: Correct. the array now fills with the right files.  downside: excel becomes unresponsive and crashes right at the beginning of your code. :D babysteps i guess. thanks a lot already.

Comment: OK. Not sure why that would be. Try walking the code with `application.screenupdating = false` etc, the usual ones.

Comment: I tried added the screenupdating I copied my code to notepad and made a new .xslm i tried running it separatly. It just goes  whirly. I can't get te watch to give me anything since the crash is instant. So weird. Is their an infinite loop I'm not getting? Thank again for all the help. :)

Comment: Step through the code rather than running it to see where the issue is. Check within the loop that "myPath" matches where it is supposed to be searching and the file path looks correct - i.e. has the "\" at the end, and everything is spelt correctly etc. Use the immidiate window and type ?myPath to see. Make sure there are at least 5 files in the directory, or else it will run forever. Change the `While myCount < 5` to `While myCount < 1` to only find one file.

Comment: I found it. It was a change that got nuchanged in one of my saving effort. .xslm to .xslx So it was the 54 files thing.

Comment: no worries. so the code now runs - does it execute `littlefiles.total` correctly and close the workbook ok?

Comment: It does now. I I added true to `ActiveWorkbook.Close true` and everything goes as suspected. Now i'm going to try and ad somthing inside littelfiles that will add a column from an external file, do the rest of littlefiles and save them as the external files, so it can be updated again from this version next time i run my magic. exciting.

Answer (score 0):

try something similar to this

```
 path = "path2folder" & "\"  'this is fairly important and probably why your code breaks?_
                               you cant add the backslash like you do above
 Filename = Dir(path & "*.xl??")

 Do While Len(Filename) > 0
     DoEvents
     Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(path & Filename, True, True)
         'add your code
     wbk.Close False
     Filename = Dir
 Loop
```

Comment: Thanks. How would I specify that the path is *wherever this file is now" + in subfolder /Departement ?  `myPath = ThisWorkbook.path & "\" & "Departement" ` ?

Comment: Also, why is there a for each inside the do while loop? What is the element of the for each? I'm confused :)

Comment: oh i just copy an dpasted from a sub i had where i loop through a directory and do things per workbook. sorry ill delete it so its clearer

Comment: Allright. but it still does not seem to do... anything.

Comment: Actually 'looping through a directory and do things per workbook' sounds exactly what I want to do.

Comment: i only posted the generic loop structure. yopu can enter your code in the appropriate spots to get it to do something

Comment: haha, yeah I got that. :D That Why I put the Call  between set wb and wb.close